# New relic + gunicorn + https issues

Tags: https, gunicorn, newrelic

I am currently using new relic to monitor my web app. In my deploy script i have the following

```
sudo NEW_RELIC_CONFIG_FILE=/<path to app>/app/config/newrelic.ini newrelic-admin run-program gunicorn 'run:run_app' -b 0.0.0.0:8000 -w3 --certfile=/<path to app>/app/config/server.crt --keyfile=/<path to app>/app/config/server.key --access-logfile log/gunicorn.log
```

The idea here is to allow for https. When testing locally I can get the https working with

```
sudo gunicorn 'run:run_app' -b 0.0.0.0:5000 -w3 --certfile=app/config/server.crt --keyfile=app/config/server.key  --access-logfile gunicorn.log
```

And the debugger shows

```
[INFO] Listening at: https://0.0.0.0:5000 (4691)
```

in the local case, and

```
[INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (9094)
```

on the server.

I've tried everything I could think of and think that this must be a problem in New Relic overriding something?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't quite enough information to go on. You might want to open a ticket at https://support.newrelic.com so that New Relic can investigate this at length.